# Strange problem when trying to read data

Tags: c#, long-integer, binaryreader

When I write:

```
var tagType = _reader.ReadByte();

while (tagType != 8)
{
    var skip = ReadNext3Bytes() + 11;
    _reader.BaseStream.Position += skip;

    tagType = _reader.ReadByte();
}
```

...it's working, but when I write:

```
var tagType = _reader.ReadByte();

while (tagType != 8)
{
    _reader.BaseStream.Position += ReadNext3Bytes() + 11; 
     tagType = _reader.ReadByte();
}
```

...it is not working, and I can't understand why - I'm getting unexpected results. Heres the `ReadNext3Bytes` method:

```
    private long ReadNext3Bytes()
    {
        try
        {
            return Math.Abs((_reader.ReadByte() & 0xFF) * 256 * 256 + (_reader.ReadByte() & 0xFF) 
                * 256 + (_reader.ReadByte() & 0xFF));
        }
        catch 
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it is not working'? An exception is being thrown? You are getting unexpected results?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting unexpected results.

Comment: What results do you expect?  What results are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens since *Position* is changed during *ReadByte* call, what you see is similar to this case:

```
int position = 1;
position += (position = 2) + 3;

Assert.AreEqual(6, position);
```

Comment: .NET stores the value of Position before it starts evaluating the right side of the assignment, best way is the simplest one: the first form you wrote that worked. The second way, which I like less is to reduce 3 from the increment expression: 
_reader.BaseStream.Position += ReadNext3Bytes() + 11 - 3;